# How setup a proxy server using node js ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, proxy

i setup a proxy using node js
my script is like this

```
var http = require('http'),
 httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var options = {
  pathnameOnly: true,
  router: {
    '/wamp_application/': '127.0.0.1:80/',
    '/node_application': '127.0.0.1:1331',
    
  }
};


var proxyServer = httpProxy.createServer(options);
proxyServer.listen(8888);
```

now its working like this
when i access  127.0.0.1:8888/wamp_application, i get 127.0.0.1:80
But i want like this

**127.0.0.1:8888/wamp_application/app1 ->    127.0.0.1:80/app1
127.0.0.1:8888/wamp_application/app2 ->    127.0.0.1:80/app2
127.0.0.1:8888/wamp_application/app3 ->    127.0.0.1:80/app3 and so on**

i tried like this

```
  router: {
        '/wamp_application/*': '127.0.0.1:80/*',
        '/node_application/*': '127.0.0.1:1331/*',
       };
```

it is not working.
actually i want both php and node application access from same port.
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to forward to ports other than 80 (a reverse proxy), nginX is a better choice. Use nginx.conf to bind your applications.

See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass